# Question on bel and decibel?

Tags: logarithms, unit-of-measure

> - What do these units of measurement mean?

In Analogue Electronic class, the Prof uses $20 \log_{10}$ and in my Networks and Protocols class, the Prof uses $10 \log_{10}$ but they both refer to  $\text{decibel}$ (unless my hearing is impaired.)

> - I would like to understand the connection of these two ($20 \log_{10}$ and $10 \log_{10}$)  to $\text{bel}$ and $\text{decibel}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Analogue Electronics prof is talking about amplitudes and the Networks and Protocols prof is talking about powers or intensities.  If a signal has intensity $x$ times the intensity of the reference level, it is $\log_{10}(x)$ bels or $10 \log_{10}(x)$ decibels.  The intensity is proportional to the square of the amplitude, so this signal's amplitude is $\sqrt{x}$ times the amplitude of the reference level, and $10 \log_{10}(x) = 20 \log_{10}(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. -b Thank you!